# Integrating a chatstorage.sqlite backup file of whatsapp into andorid phone

Tags: android, database, sqlite, backup, whatsapp

I managed to recevover from my old broken iphone a chatstorage.sqlite backup.
I have now an android phone with whatsapp but with none of my old iphone chats.
is there any way I can restore the old messages into my andorid phone?

I dont have any idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way I can restore the old messages into my andorid phone?

In short yes.

It could be accomplished in a number of ways.

The file could be copied into the assets folder and copied from the assets folder to a suitable location and opened via the SQLite api (typically as an SQliteDatabase and typically via )

- this assumes that if the database is using WAL (Write-Ahead Logging) that the database has been fully checkpointed, otherwise there could be 3 required files the database file, the -wal file (same file name but suffixed with -wal) and the -shm file (suffixed with -shm)).

The file could then be included as an asset, the asset copied and then the database opened via the SQLite API or possibly attached to the database and the data extracted.

- note that as an asset it will be distributed with the app.

You could alternately copy the database file from an online location.

You could use an SQLite tool to extract the appropriate data into a file that could included as an asset or accessed online.